# How to compare Swift String.Index?

Tags: swift

So I have an instance of `Range<String.Index>` obtained from a search method. And also a standalone `String.Index` by other means how can I tell wether this index is within the aforementioned range or not?

Example code:

```
let str = "Hello!"

let range = Range(start: str.startIndex, end: str.endIndex)
let anIndex = advance(str.startIndex, 3)

// How to tell if `anIndex` is within `range` ?
```

Since comparison operators do not work on `String.Index` instances, the only way seems to be to perform a loop through the string using `advance` but this seems overkill for such a simple operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beta 5 release notes mention:

> The idea of a Range has been split into three separate concepts:
>
> - Ranges, which are Collections of consecutive discrete `ForwardIndexType` values. Ranges  are used for slicing and iteration.
> - Intervals over `Comparable` values, which can efficiently check for containment. Intervals are  used for pattern matching in switch
>     statements and by the `~=` operator.
> - Striding over `Strideable` values, which are Comparable and can be advanced an arbitrary  distance in O(1).

Efficient containment checking is what you want, and this is possible since `String.Index` is `Comparable`:

```
let range = str.startIndex..<str.endIndex as HalfOpenInterval
// or this:
let range = HalfOpenInterval(str.startIndex, str.endIndex)

let anIndex = advance(str.startIndex, 3)

range.contains(anIndex) // true
// or this:
range ~= anIndex // true
```

(For now, it seems that explicitly naming `HalfOpenInterval` is necessary, otherwise the `..<` operator creates a `Range` by default, and `Range` doesn't support `contains` and `~=` because it uses only `ForwardIndexType`.)

Comment: Ugh, just saw the recently updated beta5. So I guess my only solution is a 2.4Gb download. : /

Comment: The same concepts should exist in beta 4 in some form. However, there's no reason to learn the old way!

Comment: In beta4, there is no `Interval` type AFAIK and the `~=` operator didn't work either : (

Comment: `String.Index` may still be `Comparable` though, and you could just implement your own `~=`.

Comment: nope. `String.Index` is not `Comparable` thus the question.

Comment: Just to clarify in case anyone else is reading this: In Beta4 the `String.Index` type does not implement `Comparable` thus the question. In Beta5 we now have `ClosedInterval` and `HalfOpenInterval` type as @jtbandes suggested and also `String.Index` type now implements `Comparable` so you just need to upgrade.